# making a get request to .json URI in java and receiving its contents

Tags: java, android, json, uri, httprequest

I have this URI http://data.seattle.gov/api/views/vncn-umqp/rows.json of type **.json** and want to make a GET request to retrieve the `data` part of the object (see the latter part of the page with "data") for plotting purposes.

Problem is I am not sure whether to use `HttpURLConnection`, `URL`,`URLConnection` or `Connection` or any other similar resource to receive a successful 200 response. Moreover, this URI's domain provides a REST API [right here](https://github.com/socrata/socrata-api-java) for request but due to inconsistencies in documentation (for example they use sun.Base64Encoder for encoding user credentials, which is not for use or unavailable) I find it really hard to employ for connection, let alone for data retrieving.

They also use an authentication method with API key but I am not sure which one does the job for the task's simplicity (i.e., which one is necessary only for reading data from this particular URI)

Can anyone provide me the solution on how to make such a request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache HttpClient to make requests to web resources, its included in the Android API. Issuing a GET request is simple enough:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://data.seattle.gov/api/views/vncn-umqp/rows.json");

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```

You can then use a JSON library to parse the response. The client also supports the other HTTP verbs (`POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` ...).

As to the second part of your question, it was somewhat confusing because it seemed to imply that this REST API was being provided by the same provider of the web service you linked, but it is not. Also, it was not immediately obvious that it is actually a REST ***client*** API. You may want to update your question to clear that up. But back on topic, you do not need to use a complicated REST client API for this, just access the content with HttpClient and process it with a JSON library.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That gave me a 200 OK! About the REST API, why do you think they have set up their own authentication `HttpConnection` class with app token parameters and stuff? Coz I have the apptoken but i dont think it should be necessary since I only want to read the data and plot them on a map. Authentication seems all the more useless unless I am writing data to their database.

Comment: I have no familiarity with their API so cannot speak to it. I know that HttpClient lets you do Basic and Digest authentication out of the box, supports SSL and can do OAuth with some help. The API you linked might be trying to put a simpler layer on top of various technologies, but like I said, I havent used it before.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the Google's Gson library to work with JSON files.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

It's very easy to integrate on your project and will ease a lot your work to parse the content of the json file.